# Про базу данных в PHP

Tags: php, база-данных

У меня две таблицы в базе данных - users и post. И там и там есть колонка login, и я хочу, чтобы в post таблице сразу выводился login из users...То есть тот логин, из которого написан message... что засунуть в переменную? Какой код? Прошу помочь!

P.S. Может неправильным путем пытаюсь решить проблему? Проблема в том, что, когда вхожу под именем "user1" все ранее написанные сообщения показываются под его именем, потом вхожу под именем "user2" и те же самые сообщения отображаются под именем "user2"... как решить проблему?

```
$login = ?;
$message = trim($_POST['message']);
$date = trim($_POST['date']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO post (login. message, date) VALUES ('$login', '$message', '$date')";
$query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
```

Comment: То, что хотите поместить в колонку login в таблице post

Comment: хочу добавить тот логин, из которого был написан пост...

Comment: Так добавте, в чем проблема то?

Comment: Почитайте про JOIN таблиц

Answer (score 0):

В таблице post у вас должна быть колонка user_id. При insert записи в post необходимо передавать туда user_id, который будет соответствовать идентифкатору пользователя в таблице users. Далее, чтобы получить записи из таблицы post вместе с полем логин необходимо построить примерно такой запрос:

```
 select * from post left join users on post.user_id=users.id
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все получилось и главное понял суть полностью!!! Супер